# how do i implement like feature with facebook c# SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using facebook C# SDK 5.3.2 for desktop application and i created desktop app using this sdk. I can now post messages but i also like and share posted messages. It seems that i should get postid and then post messages with parameter "/me/likes" along with postid. But i couln't manage it till now.

Comment: have you tried reading the documentation? [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/)

Comment: Hi Lix, ofcourse i read this documentation. But i need different solution. You answered my question before. Now i can post messages via C# SDK but i also like this post and to do this , first i need to get postid and then post messages with this id and parameters "/me/likes". But i couldn't manage it till now. This question isn't enough clear to answer??

Comment: If you want to use the like and share features without usiung the plugins you must say that that is what you want to do... The question you posted did not have enough information.  The documentation contains all the information you need.  Try it out and if you have a problem then post it here with code examples of things you have tried and any errors (if there are any :P )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the graph to like a post (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), all you need to do is HTTP post to `{post ID}/likes` without any parameters. This assumes the user has `publish_stream` permissions accepted.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

IDictionary<string, object> para = new Dictionary<string, object>();

fb.PostAsync("/" + fbphotoid + "/likes", para);
```

Because PostAsync need one parameter.